# How do I find the shortest path from bottom to top of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Say you want to cross a river from the bottom(pic below), but you can only jump on rocks to cross it. Given the positions of the rocks, how do you find the minimum amount of jumps needed to cross the river?

I got the idea that I should use BFS, but what that confuses me is what node I should start at, and how do I decide which node I should end at? Should I create a dummy vertex for the far bank? And another thing I don't understand is how to run the BFS when I "don't know" which nodes are neighbours.

Comment: Read the tag info before using the [tag:c++] tag please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy node for each side, then use a shortest path graph algorithm.

Comment: How do I run a shortest path algorithm when I(the computer) don't know which of the nodes are neighbors to eachother? One thing is of course to iterate and find the neighbors, but that isn't optimal

Comment: @Paul forget about the computer. It looks like you're being given array positions in the input. How do you, as a human reading the problem definition and sample input, know which "rocks" are next to each other? The answer to this question should make it obvious how to code something that can detect the neighboring stones given the current position. Iterating is not necessary.